# Diagonal Output of Assembly program

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

I have this assembly program and I want diagonal output of this program but I dont know how to put tabspace in assembly.

```
section    .text
    global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                 ;tell linker entry point

    mov edx, len        ;message length
    mov ecx, msg        ;message to write
    mov ebx, 1          ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax, 4          ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

    mov eax, 1          ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'Y',10,'O',10,'U',10,'S',10,'U',10,'F'  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of our dear string
```

Output of my program is:

```
Y
O 
U 
S
U 
F
```

Output should like this:

```
Y
  O
    U
      S
        U
          F
```

Is there any other way to write this program and get this output?

Comment: Are you outputting this in windows or linux console?

Comment: im outputting in windows

Comment: Um, `int 80` will not work on Windows!!!  Only under Linux!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there an other way to do this

Of course there is!  You can do it anyway that you want!  Since you say you are using Windows, but are using Linux Interrupts, this code is OS Neutral (meaning it will work on Windows or Linux)

```
extern exit, printf, malloc, free
global main

section .data
szText      db  "Gunner Diagonally!!"
Text_Len    equ $ - szText
fmtstr      db  "%s", 10, 0

section .text
main:

    push    Text_Len
    push    szText
    call    PrintDiagonal

    call    exit

;~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
;~ PrintDiagonal - Prints text to terminal diagonally
;~ In: esp + 4 = address of text to print
;~     esp + 8 = length of string to print 
;~ Returns - Nothing
;~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PrintDiagonal:
%define Text_ dword [ebp + 8]
%define TextLen_ dword [ebp + 12]
%define _Buffer dword [ebp - 4]
%define _SpaceCount dword [ebp - 8]
%define _CurLine dword [ebp - 12]

    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4 * 3

    mov     eax, TextLen_
    add     eax, eax
    push    eax
    call    malloc
    add     esp, 4 * 1
    mov     _Buffer, eax

    mov     _SpaceCount, 1
    mov     _CurLine, 1

    mov     esi, Text_ 
.NextLine:    
    mov     edi, _Buffer
    mov     edx, _SpaceCount
    dec     edx
    jz      .SpaceDone

.SpaceStart:
    mov     ecx, _SpaceCount
    dec     ecx
.FillSpaces:
    mov     byte [edi], 32
    inc     edi
    dec     ecx
    jnz     .FillSpaces

.SpaceDone:    
    mov     al, byte [esi]
    mov     byte [edi], al
    mov     byte [edi + 1], 0
    push    _Buffer
    push    fmtstr
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4 * 2

    inc     esi
    add     _SpaceCount, 2
    mov     edx, TextLen_ 
    inc     _CurLine
    cmp     _CurLine, edx
    jng     .NextLine

    push    _Buffer
    call    free
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    leave
    ret     4 * 2
```

There is no error checking, of course you would add your own.

[image: Win Diag]
[image: Linux Diag]

We take the string and add the correct spaces in a loop then print.

Answer (score 3):

You could put in your `msg`

```
msg db  'Y',10,9,'O',10,9,9,'U',10,9,9,9,'S',10,9,9,9,9,'U',10,9,9,9,9,9,'F'  ;our dear string
```

9 is ascii for tab.

[image: ascii char table]

Comment: @YousufUmar What exactly you mean by 'not working'? Error? Output not matching?

Comment: by using 9 asscii its not putting tab space infact there is no changing in my code if i put your code into mine

Comment: is there an other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows (because of DOS legacy) has separated CR (carriage return) that moves the carriage at X position 0, and LF (line feed) that moves one line down without changing the carriage X position.

In Linux LF only is used and it do both: moves the carriage down and left to 0.

In order to have the same diagonal output in Linux, you should cheat a little:

```
; replace dots with spaces.
msg db  'Y',10,'.O',10,'..U',10,'...S',10,'....U',10,'.....F'
```